# Get Buffering Parameters From an Open `FILE*`

Tags: c, file, buffer

In C, we can use [setvbuf(...)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/setvbuf/) to set a buffer, its size, and a buffering mode.  I am surprised to find that no one has asked how to *read* these values, given an open `FILE*` (e.g. `stdout`, or user-provided).  I.e., how could one implement a "`getvbuf(...)`" routine (or even a subset of it)?

```
void getvbuf(FILE* stream, char** pbuf,int* bufmode,size_t* bufsize);
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think its available as part of the standard. However Solaris has introduced some non standard mechanism to query few of these properties which are also available in GNU C compiler.

Check this for more details: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Controlling-Buffering.html

I was curious to know the use case where you want to do a getvbuf(..) kind of stuff.

Comment: I'm in that position at the moment. I have different buffering behaviour on different versions of Windows (95 vs 10) when piping output and I want to determine if it's coming from the CRT or the shell.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61843451/3316645) on a duplicate question elaborates on the information given in this answer some more and details a possible (non-portable) implementation. And regarding the motivation: imagine a library that manages and keeps track of child processes, offering user code to manipulate them (including setting and _getting_ the buffer type, etc).