# How to check the buffer type of an output stream?

Tags: c, linux

Using `setvbuf()`, we can change the buffer type of a `FILE*` stream to one of:

- `_IONBF` (unbuffered)
- `_IOLBF` (line buffered)
- `_IOFBF` (fully buffered)

For example, in order to set `stderr` to line buffered, we could do the following:

```
setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IOLBF, 0);
```

Is there also a way to figure out the current buffer type for a given output stream (using a file descriptor or FILE pointer)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible. There is no standard way of determining the current buffering characteristic of a opened `FILE`.

There are non standard functions introduced by Solaris available in GNU C library, there is [`__flbf` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Controlling-Buffering.html) in `stdio_ext.h` in GNU C library, that returns nonzero value in case the stream is line buffered.

After inspecting [glibc sources `libio/iosetvbuf.c`](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/libio/iosetvbuf.c) the following program that you shouldn't use seems to work on my platform with GNU libc 2.31:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef __GLIBC__
#define _IO_UNBUFFERED        0x0002
#define _IO_LINE_BUF          0x0200
int getvbuf(FILE *f) {
    if (f->_flags & _IO_UNBUFFERED) {
        return _IONBF;
    } else if (f->_flags & _IO_LINE_BUF) {
        return _IOLBF;
    }
    return _IOFBF;
}
#else
#error This program works only with glibc.
#endif

const char *vbuf_to_str(int a) {
    switch (a) {
    case _IONBF: return "_IONBF";
    case _IOLBF: return "_IOLBF";
    case _IOFBF: return "_IOFBF";
    }
    return "unknown";
}

int main() {
    setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    printf("%s\n", vbuf_to_str(getvbuf(stderr)));
    setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IOLBF, 0);
    printf("%s\n", vbuf_to_str(getvbuf(stderr)));
    setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IOFBF, 0);
    printf("%s\n", vbuf_to_str(getvbuf(stderr)));
}
```

Comment: Is that because `FILE` is a type without a standard implementation?

Comment: `Is that` - "that" - what exactly? Yes, `FILE` is a opaque type. The C standard doesn't specify it's implementation. I believe the committee intention is that programmers shouldn't even need to query the current buffering mode of `FILE`, so they don't provide such interface because it's not needed. But that's my guess.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant.  Is the fact that there's no standard way to get the buffering attributes is because that makes assumptions about the implementation which may not be valid?

Comment: _"it's not needed"_ - nothing is ever needed - until it is. :-)